# Google API - Contacts, incremental scopes, offline and on-line access

Tags: offline, google-contacts-api

Inching closer...

I am building a contacts synchronization facility into our product (with PHP/javascript). We are using an incremental approach for access - initially requesting a base set of scopes, then we want to expand these scopes when (if) our client decides to use the extra facility.

Base set:
    www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
    www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
    www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Extended with:
    www.google.com/m8/feeds 
    www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts

I can get the extra scopes using the gapi.auth.signIn() call, but that doesn't seem to give me a "permanent" access token to use - later requests to the API in PHP don't show the new scopes. Does that mean I have to have an explicit call to the gapi function any time I want the frontend to access contacts?

Also, how do I get an offline token that I can use for the background process that will do the synchronization? Do I have to have a separate token for offline access? Can I mix offline and online access using the same token, or do I have to have one of each?

thanks,
andy

Answer (score 1):

The difference between both online and offline access is that when you request an access token, this token will expire after certain time, usually 60 mins. After it expires the user will have to provide again the credentials so you can receive a new token. 
In this case it is an "online" token.

When requesting the access token and you provide the parameter  access_type=offline you will receive a refresh token. After the access token expires, you can request a new request token using the refresh token so it is not necessary that the user provides again the credentials.

Here you can find more information about that: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but... I read that. I have the token now, and a matching refresh token so that I can get a new access token when the old one expires. Having the refresh token removes the requirement to have the user give me permission again.  This all has been working fine for my on-line accesses.  
My first question is, will the token I have now, with the refresh token, be usable by my batch process. And the second part of that is, how can I extend the scopes available for my access token in a way that carries forward with the off-line access.